# Expression.And three conditions

Tags: c#, linq-expressions

I want to create a Expression with three conditions

But Linq.Expressions.Expression.And can take only two expressions.

I would like to have : Expression1 AND Expression2 AND Expression3

Is there a method directly in Linq.Expressions to do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to combine/nest them:

```
Expression.And(
  Expression.And(
    ...,
    ...
  ),
  ...
);
```

Comment: Since all binary operators in C# are left-associative, I'd use `And(And(x, y), z)` instead of `And(x, And(y, z))`.

Comment: What is the difference of `And(And(x, y), z)` and `And(x, And(y, z))`

Comment: @Azerty123: In this particular case, both will yield the same result and side-effects, since binary AND is an associative operation which does not short-circuit.

Answer (score 1):

In C#, `&` is a binary operator, and expression tress mirror C#.

So, the C# expression `a & b & c`, which is left-associative, really means `(a & b) & c`, and using expression trees:

```
Expresssion.And(Expression.And(a, b), c)
```

Note that if you meant to create an expression tree for the `&&` operator, which also does short-circuiting, you should be using `AndAlso`.

**Side note:** The easiest way to learn how to build expression trees is to use the C# compiler itself. For example, just compile this piece of code:

```
Expression<Func<bool>> e = () => a & b & c;
```

And examine the resulting assembly in a decompiler tool (such as ILSpy). Just be sure to turn off any optimizations that parse expression trees back into code.

Answer (score 0):

Use `And` twice

ie (pseudo-code),

```
And(condition1,And(condition1,condition2))
```

Answer (score -1):

The provided answers do address the question, but I feel a better question is: how do I apply *n* conditions?

You can do this using the `Aggregate` method, which can apply a set of a conditions to your dataset.  Example:

```
//values to filter
var values = new int[] { 1, 10, 46, 51, 58, 92, 105, 110 }.AsQueryable();
var filters = new Expression<Func<int, bool>>[] {
    i => i % 2 == 0, // integer is even
    i => i > 50,     // integer is greater than 50
    i => i < 100     // integer is less than 100
};
var result = filters.Aggregate(values, (current, expression) => current.Where(expression));
//result is { 58, 92 }
```

This is an elegant solution to most situations that deal with applying multiple filters to a set of values.